# Visual Studio Properties Window Rendering Issues, etc

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 - version 15.8.8.  As you can see from the screen shots I have issues where:

1. The Properties Window is not rendering correctly.
2. The Designer also seems to have issues.

In both cases the proper content of the window is not aligned correctly to the windows chrome, and when you reposition the window it renders unrelated parts of the screen.

It only seems to affect this one solution - I have opened another solution and could not reproduce the issue.

I have tried:

- Restarting VS.
- Rebooting laptop.
- Closing VS; Deleting the **.vs** folder; restarting VS.
- Closing VS; Deleting the **.vs** folder and **obj** folder; restarting VS.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Booted up this morning and it's resolved itself.